# Unable to clear list attribute in Component Controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have "List" attribute in Aura component,
<aura:attribute name="chkRecords" type="List" />

Due to some actions, values were added to the chkRecords in component controller. On click of button "Close" calling a controller method where I want to clear chkRecords list. So I am trying to set value to chkRecords using component.set.

closeEditMode : function(component, event, helper){
component.set("v.chkRecords", "");
}

Later when I try to perform an action on same component without refreshing the page, chkRecords contains 1 empty record not sure why list attribute is not cleared? Not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add few more detail as it is not very clear what are you trying to do in your component.

Comment: Set the value to an empty array, `component.set("v.chkRecords", []);`

Comment: Thanks Rahul Gawale. It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

List is nothing but an array in JS, so you can assign an empty array to the attribute. Like below.

`component.set("v.chkRecords", []);`